# How to escape spaces in Bash command line arguments

Tags: python, bash

Does Bash support escaping spaces in command line arguments?

I have a simple Python script using argparse to get arguments passed from Bash, but when I call it like:

```
myscript.py --name="Some Text With Spaces"
```

I get a result like:

```
args = ['Text', 'With' Spaces']
kwargs = {'name': 'Some'}
```

I though Bash support spaces with "\" but trying

```
myscript.py --name="Some\ Text\ With\ Spaces"
```

results in the same thing.

Am I misusing Bash, or is this a problem I have to deal with on Python's side?

Comment: Did you try without `=` sign?

Comment: How **exactly** are you calling the python script? Where is the command that is being run coming from? (You need *either* quotes or backslashes on spaces but not both.)

Comment: @thefourtheye That won't affect word-splitting in anyway that is relevant here. This sounds more like using a string to hold a complex command, improperly using `eval`, etc.

Comment: Assuming your script is called *exactly* as shown, your script itself receives a single argument (i.e., `sys.argv[1] == "--name=Some Text With Spaces"`). What your argument parser is doing with that argument is another question altogether.

Comment: Show us the relevant part of `myscript.py`.

Comment: `myscript.py --name="Some Text With Spaces"` works perfectly. More likely you're putting `cmd='myscript.py --name="Some Text With Spaces"'` in a variable and running `$cmd`; that'll never work, for reasons given in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: `print repr(sys.argv)` and see if that looks the way you expect to be clear on whether this problem is on the Python side or the bash side.

Answer (score 7):

Coming from the bash end, the most likely cause is that you're not telling us the truth about your bash code. What you're hitting looks a great deal like [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Running

```
myscript.py --name="Some Text With Spaces"
```

...directly from a command line works perfectly, resulting in a `sys.argv` array of `['myscript.py', '--name=Some Text With Spaces']`. The behavior you describe is consistent with this:

```
cmd='myscript.py --name="Some Text With Spaces"'
$cmd
```

...which will result in a `sys.argv` array of `['myscript.py', '--name="Some', 'Text', 'With', 'Spaces"']`.

---

Don't do that, ever. Either use an array (typically appropriate if you need to build up an argument line conditionally):

```
cmd=( myscript.py --name="Some Text With Spaces" )
"${cmd[@]}"
```

...or a function (typically the appropriate choice in all other cases):

```
myscript() { myscript.py --name="Some Text With Spaces" "$@"; }
myscript
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend storing the command name in the array. It's only in this simple case of a command plus its arguments that such an expansion works. You can't, for example, include pipes or I/O redirections in the array. The function is the better choice.

Comment: Depends on the use case. If the whole reason the command is in a variable at all is to build up its contents conditionally, then a function may not be the right tool for the job. BashFAQ #50 goes into the compromises; I've added a little more guidance here, but would rather folks read the fine FAQ. :)

Comment: Without seeing what the OP proposes to accept for such a built-up command, I'd err on the side of not executing arbitrary code.

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit into where/how I've encouraged practices that lead to execution of arbitrary code?

Comment: Sorry, "arbitrary" was a bit strong. But, for example, if `myscript.py` is hard-coded, it makes little difference if you use `"${cmd[@]}"` (with the script name included) or `myscript.py "${cmdargs[@]}"`. But if the value of `cmd` is built up from an unknown source, the script has no control (without more care being taken) over whether `"${cmd[@]}"` runs `myscript.py` or `rm`. I think it's better to make sure the script has explicit control over what *commands* are run, and let the *arguments* to that command be stored in the array.